# Spring Security - нет логина

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

Всем привет.
Есть проблема со Spring Security.
Никак не могу авторизоваться за Юзера.

Хибернейт пишет это в консоли, как я понимаю, он пытается что-то найти, но не выходит.

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.active as active2_0_, user0_.password as password3_0_, user0_.username as username4_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.username=?
```

Когда на самой форме нажимаю "Вход" в url это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 В браузере если открыть код, то есть одна ошибка, но, что она означает не понимаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, где скорее всего я косячу и на что первым делом обратить внимание. 
Если понадобится код - скину.
Спасибо.

P.s сделал страничку, чтобы отобразить пользователей которые есть в БД. Все без проблем отобразилось. + так же добавил на нее logout - он также, как ожидается работает.

Comment: Hibernate в консоли пишет отладочный вывод sql-запросов, это не ошибка. А ошибка в консоли браузера связана с тем, что на странице есть изображение или медиа-элемент, ссылка на который не загружается. Почему не проходит аутентификация из приведённых вами данных понять невозможно.

Comment: По ошибкам - понял, спасибо. По нехватке данных -какие классы/темплейты вам необходимы? - Я добавлю.

Comment: Spring Security тяжело отлаживать удалённо, слишком уж он гибок. Может у вас там конфигурация контекста безопасности в одну строку, а может собственные реализации AuthenticationProvider и UserDetailsService.

Comment: Немного разобрался - исправил ошибку (даже не ошибку, опечатался в одном месте). Теперь логин происходит, но не понимаю, как мне перейти со страницы логина при успешной авторизации дальше. Почему-то дальше не идет. Подскажите, в чем проблема в этот раз.

Comment: Уже все. Все проблемы решил - Sergey, спасибо.